# Building Grails App Using Gradle

Tags: grails, gradle, gvm, quickbuild

I'm trying to build a Grails app using Gradle by calling the grails executable directly (instead of using any plugins/wrappers).  I'd rather not lose the ability to use BuildConfig.groovy so I figured this would work.  It works fine using windows syntax on my machine, but when I try to modify it to work with PMEase QuickBuild on a Linux machine it won't work.  Seems that the QuickBuild admin didn't add $GRAILS_HOME/bin to the path on the box and is hesitant to do so because there may be additional versions of Grails installed on the box since it's a shared build server.  I tried setting the workingDir in the task and that fails with the non-helpful "Process 'command './grails'' finished with non-zero exit value 1" and no further info.

```
task buildWAR(type: Exec) {

    commandLine './grails', 'dev', 'war', '--debug', '--stacktrace',  '--verbose'

    standardOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream()

    ext.output = {
        return standardOutput.toString()
    }

}
```

So is this possible?  If he were to install/use GVM would I be able to somehow integrate a "gvm use" statement in my Gradle script?

Answer (score 0):

Ran the build command directly on the machine and came to the conclusion that it couldn't hit our internal maven repo due to firewall. Migrated dependencies to a repo it could hit and it built the WAR properly.